# Extract single href from a web page

Tags: python, regex, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am working on a code, in which I have to extract a single href link, the problem which I am facing is that it extracts two links which have everything same except the last ID part, I have one ID, I just want to extract the other one from the link. This is my code:-

```
    import requests,re
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
    url="http://www.barneys.com/band-of-outsiders-oxford-sport-shirt-500758921.html"
    r=requests.get(url)
    soup=BeautifulSoup(r.content)
    g_1=soup.find_all("div",{"class":"color-scroll"})
    for item in g_1:
          a_1=soup.find_all('a', href=re.compile('^/on/demandware.store/Sites-BNY-Site/default/Product-Variation'))
          for elem in a_1:
               print elem['href']
```

The output which I am getting is:-

```
         /on/demandware.store/Sites-BNY-Site/default/Product-Variation?pid=500758921
         /on/demandware.store/Sites-BNY-Site/default/Product-Variation?pid=500758910
```

I have the first ID i.e, 500758921, I want to extract the other one.
Please Help. Thanks in advance!

Comment: is it *always * the second link that you need, or sometimes the first or 3rd?

Comment: it depends, that how many other ID's are there to extract, sometimes the second one or sometimes both second and third one

Comment: @VaibhavSinha do you mean that you need every link except the first one?..

Comment: yes, more specifically, every id except the first one!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need every link except the first one, just slice the result of `find_all()`:

```
links = soup.find_all('a', href=re.compile('^/on/demandware.store/Sites-BNY-Site/default/Product-Variation'))
for link in links[1:]:
    print link['href']
```

The reason that slicing works is that `find_all()` returns a `ResultSet` instance which is based internally on regular Python list:

```
class ResultSet(list):
    """A ResultSet is just a list that keeps track of the SoupStrainer
    that created it."""
    def __init__(self, source, result=()):
        super(ResultSet, self).__init__(result)
        self.source = source
```

---

To extract the `pid` from the links you've got, you can use a regular expression search saving the `pid` value in a *capturing group*:

```
import re

pattern = re.compile("pid=(\w+)")
for item in g_1:
    links = soup.find_all('a', href=re.compile('^/on/demandware.store/Sites-BNY-Site/default/Product-Variation'))
    for link in links[1:]:
        match = pattern.search(link["href"])
        if match:
            print match.group(1)
```

Comment: Link is fine, I need to extract every id too except the first one

Answer (score 0):

Run this regex for every link

```
^/on/demandware.store/Sites-BNY-Site/default/Product-Variation\?pid=([0-9]+)
```

Get the result from the last regex group.

Answer (score 0):

this might do :

```
import requests,re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
def getPID(url):
    return re.findall('(\d+)',url.rstrip('.html'))
url="http://www.barneys.com/band-of-outsiders-oxford-sport-shirt-500758921.html"
having_pid = getPID(url)
print(having_pid)
r=requests.get(url)
soup=BeautifulSoup(r.content)
g_1=soup.find_all("div",{"class":"color-scroll"})
for item in g_1:
    a_1=soup.find_all('a', href=re.compile('^/on/demandware.store/Sites-BNY-Site/default/Product-Variation'))
    for elem in a_1:
        if (getPID(elem['href'])[0] not in having_pid):
           print elem['href']
```